# Within <Stack.Navigator>, can I call an onFocus function?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm using React Navigation 6.x in React Native with Expo.

In my App.js file, I register my screens with:

```
return (
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="ResolveAuth"
    component={ResolveAuthScreen}
    options={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}
  />

  ...

</Stack.Navigator>
);
```

I would like to save the current screen to AsyncStorage. I can certainly add listeners to each individual screen to accomplish this but to keep the code a bit cleaner for each screen, I was hoping to be able to add some sort of code to each <Stack.Screen /> that would do this. (Or do something else entirely.)

I would like something along the lines of the following:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  onFocus={() => {AsyncStorage.setItem('currentScreen': 'Home')}} // I want to do this
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `onFocus` like that wont work. You need to add this functionality within the screen component.

import `useFocusEffect` from react-navigation and inside your component call the `useFocusEffect`

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

useFocusEffect(
 React.useCallback(() => {
  console.log('focus effect called')
  AsyncStorage.setItem('currentScreen', 'Home')
 }, [])
)
```

Comment: Thank you but that's exactly what I was trying to avoid, I wanted the code in my App.js file so I have less on each screen but perhaps that's the only option.